# Difference between count command and real total number of rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, row, sqlyog

I use SQlyog Ultimate-MySQL, When I use **count** command to count all rows of a table, the result is different from the real total number of rows, what does this difference mean? How can I count real total number of rows?

Comment: The value from `SELECT COUNT(*)` **is** the *real total number of rows*.   Which other total, what "difference" are you referring to?

Comment: I use this command: select count(*) from tb_name , some columns' values are null but not all of columns in one row!! so it should return total number of rows, but it doesnot match with real total number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

COUNT(column) only counts NOT NULL values. To count real total, you can use COUNT(1) (or COUNT(0), COUNT('foo'), or pretty much anything - but COUNT(*) may be slower)

Answer (score 0):

The `COUNT(column_name)` function returns the number of values (`NULL` values will not be counted) of the specified column.

Comment: I use this command: select count(*) from tb_name , some columns' values are null but not all of columns in one row!! so it should return total number of rows.